# How to print own text like"Enter valid ID", If Cursor return null value?

Tags: android

Any one help me. I want to print some suggestion if Cursor value return as null.
This is method of helper class for display data for corresponding ID

```
public Cursor display(int id) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

DBHelper=new DatabaseHelper(context);

db=DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor mCursor =

               db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                  KEY_ISBN}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null,
                   null, null, null, null);
                if (mCursor != null) {
                  mCursor.moveToFirst();
                }

                return mCursor;
```

and this is my activity class from where iam calling display()

```
public void onClick(View v) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

int id=Integer.parseInt(inputid.getText().toString());


DBAdapter dbadapter = new DBAdapter(v.getContext());

 Cursor c=dbadapter.display(id);

 if(c!=null)

 Toast.makeText(this, "Name: " + c.getString(1) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 else

 Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Valid ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this rawQuery : 
    public Cursor getSubDirectory(String parentId, String orderby, String order){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+DOCUMENTS+ " where "+DatabaseConstant.key_DOCUMENT_PARENT_ID +" = "+parentId+" ORDER BY "+orderby +" "+ order ;
        return myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }